# Reading filecontents into webbrowser control strips away my umlauts

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, diacritics

I'm using

```
private void infoLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = "infoFiles\\Tastenkürzel.htm";
            System.IO.StreamReader infoFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            string page = infoFile.ReadToEnd();
            frmInfo infoForm = new frmInfo(page);
            infoForm.Show();
        }
```

to open an html file containing umlauts. When I open the file in a browser, it shows all the dots above letters I want it to, however, once I open the filecontents in the webbrowser control, the umlauts are replaced by little boxes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem required adding an Encoding parameter.

```
System.IO.StreamReader infoFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: That can't be the solution, StreamReader already defaults to utf8.  Encoding.Default is the usual solution.